# My api youtube doesnt send messages (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

i try to learn the youtube api with Oauth but i have a problem. I can like a video but when i try to add a commentary, they have no error but nothing is send. there is my code (i'm sorry, he's not really beautiful again)

```
def insert_comment(youtube, channel_id, video_id, text):
    insert_result = youtube.commentThreads().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body=dict(
            snippet=dict(
                channelId=channel_id,
                VideoId=video_id,
                topLevelComment=dict(
                    snippet=dict(
                        textOriginal=text)
                )
            )
        )
    ).execute()

    comment = insert_result["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
    author = comment["snippet"]["authorDisplayName"]
    text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]

    print("Inserted comment for %s: %s"%(author, text))



credentials = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    print('Loading Credentials From File...')
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)


# Google's Request
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


# If there are no valid credentials available, then either refresh the token or log in.
if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
        print('Refreshing Access Token...')
        credentials.refresh(Request())
    else:
        print('Fetching New Tokens...')
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secrets.json',
            scopes=[
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
            ]
        )

        flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent',
                              authorization_prompt_message='')
        credentials = flow.credentials

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:

            print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
            pickle.dump(credentials, f)

print(credentials.to_json())

youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)
youtube.videos().rate(rating='like', id='oXtNAwfPPDE').execute()

insert_comment(youtube, "UC_n0NUFlpVSrQLfxS8uezog", "oXtNAwfPPDE", "super")
```

and when i launch it, it says me "inserted comment blabla"
the like functions without problem.

I really don't understand where is my misstake
Thanks for helping

Comment: You have a typo: use `videoId` instead of `VideoId` when calling for `CommentThreads.insert` API endpoint.

Comment: oh thanks, i'm stupid. I lost more than 30 mn for a Caps :(